# Sorting data with conditions for multiple columns in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following:

```html
df1<-read.table(text=" Id Item Group Hard
Id Item Group Hard
12 B12 A Y
14 B6 B N
17 B5 D Y
33 B10 D Y
44 B12 D N
55 B6 D Y
75 B5 D Y
44 B10 A Y
33 B12 D N
21 B6 A Y
16 B12 A N
",header=TRUE)
```

I want to match my data using the ids. I want to get B12 if they are "Y" and "N" in the Hard column, I want to get B6 if they are only "Y" in hard Column.

I want to get the following table:

```html
id Item Group Hard
12 B12 A Y
44 B12 D N
55 B6 D Y
33 B12 D N
21 B6 A Y
16 B12 A N
```

I understand I need to tell you my effort, But I have searched  but I could not find any solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there are only 'Y', 'N', in 'Hard' column, the first condition can be only on the 'Item' column and the second condition can use the 'Y' in 'Hard'

```
subset(df1, Item == 'B12'| (Item == 'B6' & Hard == 'Y'))
#    Id Item Group Hard
#2  12  B12     A    Y
#6  44  B12     D    N
#7  55   B6     D    Y
#10 33  B12     D    N
#11 21   B6     A    Y
#12 16  B12     A    N
```

With `dplyr`, change the `subset` to `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df1, Item == 'B12'| (Item == 'B6' & Hard == 'Y'))
```

Comment: Thank you, akrun

Comment: @User20100  Just use `subset(df1, Item != "B12")` and if there many other 'Item' and you want only 'B6', then `subset(df1, Item == "B6" & Hard == "Y")`

Comment: @User20100  Do you need `subset(df1, !(Item == "B12"  & Hard != "Y"))`

Comment: @User20100  It would be easier to understand as I am not clear about the expected